# Format Exception in Servicestack.Redis

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack

I am getting following error in Redis:

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters."

Any pointers will be helpful.

---

Code for storing data in Redis:

```cs
// Serialize DataTable to byte
object byteCachedDatatable = m_oSerializer.SerializeObject(oCacheObject);

// Add Serialized bytes to Redis and update expiration time
client.Set(sCacheKey, JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(byteCachedDatatable), new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, (iExpiryTimeInMins * 60)));
```

Code for getting data from Redis, throws an exception:

```cs
using (var client = new RedisClient(m_sredisHost))
{
    var values = client.GetValue(sCacheKey);
    m_arrCacheData = (byte[])JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString(values, typeof(byte[]));

    // Convert value to datatable object
    return m_arrCacheData;
}
```

Data stored in Redis:

> AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAMAgAAAE5TeXN0ZW0uRGF0YS//////////Cw==

While data coming from Redis:

> \"AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAMAgAAAE5TeXN0ZW0uRGF0YS//////////Cw==\"

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the code that caused the error, and the associated data?

Comment: @Scott added code sample. Getting data from redis throws an exception.

Comment: I got a reason for this exception but not able to figure out why while getting data i am getting extra \" \"

Comment: Got solution use setvalue() instead of set() while putting data in Redis :)

Comment: @Pritam That's good. You should create an actual answer for your question so others know you got the answer without have to read through all these comments.